# a alternative way to get the maximum value of the magnitude of the composite vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, vector-spaces, complex-geometry

To the best of our knowledge,in two-dimensional [Complex space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdzA0.png), there are N vectors in arbitrary directions. Using "Method One," by fixing one vector among the N vectors and independently rotating the remaining N-1 vectors, it is possible to maximize the magnitude of the composite vector obtained by rotating and superimposing these N vectors in this manner.

If rotating vectors according to the alternative way("Method Two"):

1. Select any vector $v_i$ with the index i from the N vectors.
2. The composite vector of the remaining N-1 vectors, excluding $v_i$, is denoted as $C=\sum_{j≠i}^N v_j$.
3. Fixing the vector C, rotate $v_i$ towards vector C($v_i$ and C colinear) to maximize the magnitude of vector $(C+v_i)$, updating the i-th vector $v_i$ to $v_i'$.
4. Next, select vector $v_j$ with index $j (j≠i)$, recursively loop through N vectors repeating steps 1, 2, and 3.

Through multiple iterations repeating steps 1, 2, 3, and 4 with N vectors, can the magnitude of the composite vector obtained through ‘Method Two’ approach the magnitude of the composite vector obtained through ‘Method One’?

Can anyone provide a mathematically rigorous proof for this problem?

[image: !enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

The First method is feasible. The second method however, According to me, has some issues with it.

Issue 1:
Say you have a set $(S)$ of vectors in the Argand plane,
$$S=\left\{A_{k}e^{i\theta_{k}},\ \forall\ k∊\left\{1,2,3...n\right\}\right\}$$
And denoting
$$C_{all}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}e^{i\theta_{k}}$$
Your First step involves choosing a vector, so let me choose a vector $A_{p}e^{i\theta_{p}}$

Next step involves defining a fixed vector, so I define $C_{p}$ as follows.
$$C_{p}=\sum_{k=1\left(k\ne p\right)}^{n}A_{k}e^{i\theta_{k}}$$
Now keeping $C_{p}$ fixed, I shall rotate the chosen vector along $C_{p}$ and add.

Now the problem starts from here.
In the next step, suppose a choose another vector $A_{q}e^{i\theta_{q}}$
Now again, defining $C_{q}$ as
$$C_{q}=\sum_{k=1\left(k\ne q\right)}^{n}A_{k}e^{i\theta_{k}}$$
Now keeping $C_{q}$ fixed, I shall rotate the newly chosen vector along $C_{q}$ and add.

Now observe these two vectors. They are not related to each other in any way!
If you repeat this process N times, you will get N different vectors in different directions with no correlation between them.
n
Issue 2:
Repeat the process of choosing a vector from the set.
Now suppose you calculate $C_{p}$ and it turns out to be zero! (It can surely happen). Then what is the algorithm supposed to do?

For example consider $n+1$ vectors such that the first $n$ are the roots to the equation $z^{n}-1=0$ and the remaining one is any vector (suppose $A_{p}e^{i\theta_{p}}$).

Now, during the repetition process, the moment you (arbitrarily) choose $A_{p}e^{i\theta_{p}}$, your $C_{p}$ will now turn out to be zero because the sum of the roots of the equation $z^{n}-1=0$ is $0$ (whose direction is not defined in the complex plane). Now when you add $\vec 0$ and $A_{p}e^{i\theta_{p}}$, which direction are you supposed to rotate your chosen vector and add?

If you are able elaborate on your method, I could try and form a mathematical expression.

Comment: hi Omkar thanks for your attention. Issue 1:for the chosen vector $A_p e^{iθ_p}$
,the $θ_p$ will be updated.so they will have correlation between them.About Issue2 :sorry I can not understand it, can you give more explanation.

Comment: @vince, I have elaborated issue 2. You can go through and check once. Issue 2 does not seem that important, but once you relate the $\theta_{k}$, it will matter.

Comment: hi Omakar sorry I am late.about issue2:you are right.When this special case happened,we can rotate the $A_p e^{iθ_p}$ to any direction.what we care about is ‘through multiple iterations repeating steps 1, 2, 3, and 4 with N vectors’ the 'method 2' can approach 'method 1'